# How to get Google cloud function execution event in node.js using firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Below is google cloud function , deployed properly and is working fine 
path to function - functions/index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.createUser = functions.firestore
.document('users/{userId}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const newValue = snap.data();
    console.log(newValue);
});
```

how can i access this function's event on successful invocation in node.js app 
  something like

```
const myFunctions = require("./functions/index");

myFunctions.createUser().then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

As of now getting below error
[image]

Comment: I want to listen to these events in my node app but createUser() is invoked from mobile app , so what should be the workaround for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `createUser` Cloud Function is triggered by a Firestore `onCreate()` event type and therefore will be "triggered when a document is written for the first time", as per the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events).

The doc also adds the following:

> In a typical lifecycle, a Cloud Firestore function does the following:
>
> 1. Waits for changes to a particular document. (In this case when the document is written for the first time)
> 2. Triggers when an event occurs and performs its tasks
> 3. Receives a data object that contains a snapshot of the data stored in the specified document.

Therefore, if you want to trigger this Cloud Function from "the outside world", e.g. from a node.js app, you need to create a new Firestore document at the corresponding location, i.e. under the `users` collection. To this end you would use the Node.js Server SDK, see https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.14.x/

Note that you could also trigger it from a client application (web, android, iOS) by creating a new `user` doc with the corresponding client SDK.

---

**Update following your comments:**

You cannot directly "port" and run your code written for Cloud Functions to a Node.js app. You will have to re-develop your solution for Node.js.

In your case you should use the Node.js Server SDK (as mentionned in my comment) and you could use the `onSnapshot` method of a CollectionReference.  See https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.14.x/CollectionReference#onSnapshot

Comment: I want to listen to these events in my node app but createUser() is invoked from mobile app , so what should be the code for this in node ?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "createUser() is invoked from mobile app"? According to your code, createUser() is a Cloud Function that is triggered in the **back end** by a Firestore onCreate() event type. So how do you invoke it from the mobile app? Can you be more precise.

Comment: When i add record to users/{userId} from mobile app ,
below event is triggered ,so i want to listen to this event in node - 
 
toexports.createUser = functions.firestore
.document('users/{userId}')

How to achieve this ?

Comment: @YogeshwarTanwar Ok, I understand! I have updated my answer, I hope it will help.

Comment: Glad that I could help you. You may consider upvoting the answer if you think it is valuable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer your question, but it's a bit unclear. You asked:

> How to get Google cloud function execution event

Well, the event has started when the funcion triggers and your code is running, i.e your line `const newValue = snap.data()`

Maybe you are looking for a way to do certain tasks, when the trigger has run? You simply just do that from inside the function, and return a promise. If you for example had multiple async tasks to run, you could use a Promise.all([]).